# Anyone know of a good and fault tolerant chat application and/or API

Tags: javascript, api, node.js, erlang, chat

Does anyone know of a good in-browser chat API and/or completed solution?

I'd be interested in both open source and closed source options that would have to be purchased.

Here are some ideal requirements:

- Message encryption
- Written in a language and/or using frameworks optimized for chat (like NodeJS / Erlang / Javascript using WebSockets, etc).
- Highly fault tolerant
- Embeddable in a browser with a fluid and friendly UI
- Highly customizable (if a completed solution)

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Jabber/[XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) is pretty good. (Not real sure about every list item, but it's worth checking out.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115746/chat-application-node-js-or-ape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) is a Jabber/XMPP instant messaging server.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [IRCCloud](https://irccloud.com/).